# CakePHP 3 cannot save associated model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am updating some log data in some tables. I can't save on the associated model ModulesEmployees only the top level CoursesEmployees. Cant see what is missing.

CoursesEmployeeTable.php

```
    $this->hasMany('ModulesEmployees', [
        'dependent' => true,
        'foreignKey' => 'courses_employee_id'
    ]);
```

ModulesSlidesController.php

```
$this->loadModel('CoursesEmployees');

$CoursesEmployee = $this->CoursesEmployees
     ->get(65, [
           'contain' => ['ModulesEmployees'],
           'where' =>[
                ['ModulesEmployees.id' => 19]
            ]
        ]);

if (!$CoursesEmployee['modules_employees'][0]['started_on']) {
    $CoursesEmployee['modules_employees'][0]['started_on'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
};

$this->CoursesEmployees->save($CoursesEmployee, ['associated' => ['ModulesEmployees']]);
```

Returned Object

```
CoursesEmployee(array)
id65
employee_id3
course_id1
course_module_id1
completed_modules0
current_slide0
cid0
date_started(array)
progress0
modified(array)
created(array)
completed(false)
date_completed(null)
deleted(null)
modules_employees(array)
    0(object)
        id19
        courses_employee_id65
        course_module_id1
        started_on2015-10-04 21:00:10
        completed_on(null)
        completed(false)
        deleted(null)
[new](false)
[accessible](array)
[dirty](empty)
[original](empty)
[virtual](empty)
[errors](empty)
[repository]CoursesEmployees
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only dirty entities/properties are being saved, and what you are doing there, modifying a nested entity, will only mark that nested entity as dirty, the parent entity, `CoursesEmployee` will remain unchanged, and therefore the saving process won't touch the associations.

When not using the patching mechanism which automatically marks parent entity properties as dirty, then you'll have to do that on your own.

Quote from the docs:

> [...]
>
> If you are building or modifying association data after building your
>   entities you will have to mark the association property as modified
>   with dirty():
>
> ```
> $company->author->name = 'Master Chef';
> $company->dirty('author', true);
> ```

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations)**

So in your case it's the `modules_employees` property that needs to be marked as dirty, like

```
$CoursesEmployee->dirty('modules_employees', true);
```